# Составить алгоритм и написать программу вычисления наибольшего общего делителя двух произвольных положительных целых чисел

Tags: c++

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <cstdlib> // для функций rand() и srand()
#include <ctime> // для функции time()
int main()
{
    float a, b;
    
    srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(0))); // устанавливаем значение системных часов в качестве стартового числа

    for (int count = 0; count < 100; ++count)
    {
        std::cout << rand() << "\t";

        // Если вывели 5 чисел, то вставляем символ новой строки
        if ((count + 1) % 5 == 0)
            std::cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Числа получить от генератора случайных чисел
Предусмотреть вывода значения полученного на устройство печати. И тут я немного не понимаю как дальше.

Comment: гуглите "алгоритм эвклида"

Comment: Выбирайте любой из [ответов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A195342+gcd) :) Непонятно только, а сами вы искать не умеете?...

Comment: если не знать, что это алгоритм Эвклида, то это сложно сделать

Answer (score 1):

> написать программу вычисления наибольшего общего делителя двух произвольных положительных целых чисел

Алгоритм Евклида для вычисления наибольшего общего делителя:

```
int GCD(int a, int b) {
    while(a && b) if (a < b) b %= a; else a %= b;
    return (a == 0) ? b : a;
    }
```

Основан на том, что НОД у чисел a и b тот же, что и у меньшего числа и остатка от деления на него большего.

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]